# Foreground Extraction of (quick time movie, i.e; .mov) video file using a static scene (a static background image) in Open CV

Tags: opencv, background-foreground

I'm new to Open CV and present working on my project which needs background separation done with OpenCV.

Two days back I configured Open CV with Visual Studio C++ 2010 and worked on small tutorials.

But I am not sure about how to make the background separation from a video file using its background image scene that I am having on my disk...

Can anyone please suggest me with some code that could help me in **extracting the background from video (type: quick time movie, i.e; .mov)by using static background image scene (.jpeg).**

I'm using some sample codes from the documentation, but i am not able to customize accordingly.

As a part, I request anything please do suggest me some code that enables me to:

Reading (quick time movie .mov file) and performing background separation on that video using the (static background scene .jpeg)